# Cors in Ajax Meet 302 Redirect

Tags: redirect, cross-domain, axios

I have a front-end server with port 8081
a background server with port 8080(Spring MVC + shiro)

When I send a request to 8080, I have to set the cors headers on 8080

If the request is a simply request which only returns some json datas, it works

But When the response status is 302, Chrome shows

> Redirect from 'http://localhost:8080/' to 'http://localhost:8080/' has
>   been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
>   is present on the requested resource.

I thought there are two reasons to occur this problem:

① if I intercept this 302 status, and deal this `response.headers.Location`,
I will solve this. But I can't intercept this response(with axios)

② Maybe some settings is wrong with 8080 server, when 302 occurs, the serve haven't set the cors Headers for this page. But I don't understand the backend code.

So, ① is feasible? or I need to change the settings on 8080 server?

Comment: this question is hard to understand, please consult this page and edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

CORS cross-domain will send a request to the OPTIONS in advance, this request does not attach tokens, this leads to shiro intercepted request to determine the current user is not logged in, causing problems, the solution is to inherit FormAuthenticationFilter.

```
@Override
protected boolean isAccessAllowed(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, Object mappedValue) {
  boolean allowed = super.isAccessAllowed(request, response, mappedValue);
  if (!allowed) {
    String method = WebUtils.toHttp(request).getMethod();
    if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS", method)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return allowed;
}
```